# How to provide a i18n compliant validation message if an invalid email is provided in html5

Tags: html, internationalization

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

How to provide a i18n compliant validation message if an invalid email is provided in html5. Currently it throws an validation message "Please enter an email address", not sure where this is being picked from?

Answer (score 3):

This message is coming from the browser itself, although much to my surprise, switching your locale in Firefox 13, at least, does not change the message. A colleague reports that downloading a different-language version of Firefox, however, does change the message.

It seems like we really will need some standardization and customization as HTML5 catches on. Otherwise we start getting worse user experience by using the new fields than we got without them.

Answer (score 1):

Map your translations using the input's `validity` ?

https://caniuse.com/constraint-validation available on evergreen browsers

```js
let locale = 'fr';

const translations = {
  en: {
    valueMissing: 'Your age is required',
    rangeUnderflow: 'You must be major to continue',
    rangeOverflow: 'You are too old, verify the number',
    // ...
  },
  fr: {
    valueMissing: 'Vous devez inscrire votre age',
    rangeUnderflow: 'Vous devez être majeur pour continuer',
    rangeOverflow: 'Vous être trop vieux, vérifiez le nombre',
    // ...
  }
}

function updateErrorMessage(inputEl, errorEl) {
  const errors = [];
  for (const key in inputEl.validity) {
   if (key==='valid') continue;
   if (inputEl.validity[key]) {
     const localTranslations = translations[locale] || {};
     errors.push(localTranslations[key] || inputEl.validationMessage || key)
   }
  }
    
  const errorMessage = errors.join('. ')
  errorEl.innerText = errorMessage;
  inputEl.style.backgroundColor = errors.length > 0
    ? 'red'
    : 'limegreen';
}

const _ = (id) => document.getElementById(id)

_('age').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  updateErrorMessage(_('age'), _('age-error'))
})

_('lang').value = locale;
_('lang').addEventListener('change', (el) => {
  locale = el.target.value;
  updateErrorMessage(_('age'), _('age-error'))
  _('age').select();
})
```

```css
input, select {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius: .25em;
}

strong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<label for="age">What's your language?</label>
<select id="lang">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">Français</option>
</select>

<br />
<br />

<label for="age">What's your age?</label>
<input id="age" required min="18" max="140" type="number" step="1" />
<p><strong id="age-error"></strong></p>

</body>
</html>
```